# Can't unistall codeblocks from ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, codeblocks, uninstallation

I'm having a problem with this program which I can't uninstall.
Everytime I try to remove or purge it this output is shown:

```
luis@Luis-PC:~/Downloads$ sudo apt purge codeblocks
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 codeblocks-contrib : Depends: libwxsmithlib0 (= 20.03) but 20.03-3 is to be installed
                      Depends: codeblocks (= 20.03) but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: valgrind but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: cppcheck but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: cscope but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: cccc but it is not going to be installed
 codeblocks-dev : Depends: libcodeblocks0 (= 20.03) but 20.03-3 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your teminal and type `sudo apt-get remove codeblocks && sudo apt-get autoremove codeblocks`